# R: Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : Can't have empty classes in y

Tags: r, random-forest, factors, levels

Ok,  I am getting the error

"Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : Can't have empty classes in y."

When running Randomforest in my code.

This is the code I am trying to run

```
set.seed(415)

trainingdata <- data.combined[1:891,]
testdata <- data.combined[892:1309,]

fitRF <- randomForest(as.factor(Survived) ~ Pclass + avg.fare + new.title + Parch + FamilyID2, 
                      data=trainingdata,
                      importance =T,
                      ntree=2000)

fitRF
varImpPlot(fitRF)


Prediction <- predict(fitRF, testdata)
submit <- data.frame(PassengerID = testdata$PassengerId, Survived = Prediction)
write.csv(submit, file="14072017_3_RF.csv", row.names = F)
```

When I run the fitRF <- randomForest line, i get the error.  I have looked at the structures of both my trainingdata and my testdata and they are identical, all variable types match with corresponding levels as below.

[image]

[image]

I just cant figure out whats going on

I read something about it may be to do with a factor levels issue so I then tried running the commands below to create my separated data from my combined data set,

```
trainingdata <- droplevels(data.combined[1:891,])
testdata <- droplevels(data.combined[892:1309,])
```

This just resulted in the levels for FamilyID2 not being equal, one was 22 the other was 18.

Comment: In your training data are all three levels of Survived represented?

Comment: Thats a good point, in the training data Survived is populated by 1s and 0s, in the test data it is represented by a value of None.   How would I get it to take this into account?  do I need to replace the None values in test?

Comment: That's your error.  Your have empty classes ("None") in your data that you're inputting into the random forest.  The 'y' in "Can't have empty classes in y" represents the response variable.

Comment: perfect thank you, so i ran trainingdata$Survived <- droplevels(trainingdata$Survived) and that is now working.